# Error when using mean() in R: Error in Ops.factor(obs, pred) : level sets of factors are different

Tags: r, mean

I'm working with a dataset looking like this:

```
> head(test_accuracy)
        observed predicted new_predicted
1 Moving/Feeding  Foraging      Standing
2       Standing  Foraging      Standing
3       Standing  Foraging      Standing
4       Standing  Foraging      Standing
5       Standing  Foraging      Standing
6       Standing  Foraging      Standing
```

My question is simple. I would like to calculate an accuracy measure of classification by comparing the percentage of matches between `test_accuracy$observed` and `test_accuracy$new_predicted`. I'm simply using the code below but I'm getting the associated error:

```
> head(test_accuracy)
        observed predicted new_predicted
1 Moving/Feeding  Foraging      Standing
2       Standing  Foraging      Standing
3       Standing  Foraging      Standing
4       Standing  Foraging      Standing
5       Standing  Foraging      Standing
6       Standing  Foraging      Standing
> obs<-as.factor(test_accuracy$observed)
> pred<-as.factor(test_accuracy$new_predicted)
> mean(obs == pred)
Error in Ops.factor(obs, pred) : level sets of factors are different
```

Could somebody please let me know what am I doing wrong? I can upload a `dput()` sample below:

```
> dput(test_accuracy)
structure(list(observed = c("Moving/Feeding", "Standing", "Standing", 
"Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Moving/Feeding", "Standing", "Standing", "Feeding/Moving", "Standing", 
"Standing", "Moving/Feeding", "Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving", 
"Feeding/Moving", "Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Standing", 
"Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", "Standing", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Moving/Feeding", "Standing", 
"Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Moving/Feeding", "Standing", 
"Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", "Standing", 
"Standing", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", "Standing", "Standing", "Standing", 
"Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving", 
"Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", "Standing", 
"Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Feeding/Moving", "Standing", 
"Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Standing", "Moving/Feeding", "Standing", "Standing", "Feeding/Moving", 
"Feeding/Moving", "Standing", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Standing", "Moving/Feeding", "Feeding/Moving", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Moving/Feeding", "Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving", 
"Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving", "Standing", 
"Standing", "Moving/Feeding", "Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving", 
"Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving", 
"Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving", 
"Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving", 
"Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Feeding/Moving", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Moving/Feeding", "Standing", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Moving/Feeding", "Standing", "Standing", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Moving/Feeding", "Standing", "Standing", "Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving", 
"Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving", 
"Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving", 
"Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving", 
"Standing", "Moving/Feeding", "Standing", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", "Standing", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Moving/Feeding", "Feeding/Moving", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", "Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving", 
"Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Moving/Feeding", "Standing", "Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving", 
"Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving", 
"Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving", 
"Feeding/Moving", "Moving/Feeding", "Standing", "Standing", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Standing", "Moving/Feeding", "Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving", 
"Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving", 
"Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving", "Feeding/Moving"), predicted = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("Feeding", "Foraging", "Standing"
), class = "factor"), new_predicted = c("Standing", "Standing", 
"Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Moving/Feeding", "Standing", "Moving/Feeding", "Standing", "Standing", 
"Standing", "Standing", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Moving/Feeding", "Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Standing", "Standing", "Moving/Feeding", "Standing", "Standing", 
"Standing", "Standing", "Moving/Feeding", "Standing", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", "Standing", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Standing", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Moving/Feeding", "Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Standing", 
"Standing", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", "Standing", "Standing", 
"Standing", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Moving/Feeding", "Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Standing", 
"Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Standing", 
"Moving/Feeding", "Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Standing", 
"Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", "Standing", "Standing", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Standing", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", "Standing", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Standing", "Moving/Feeding", "Standing", "Standing", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Standing", 
"Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Standing", 
"Standing", "Standing", "Moving/Feeding", "Standing", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Standing", "Moving/Feeding", "Standing", "Moving/Feeding", "Standing", 
"Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Standing", 
"Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Standing", "Standing", "Moving/Feeding", "Standing", "Standing", 
"Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Moving/Feeding", "Standing", 
"Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Standing", 
"Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Moving/Feeding", "Standing", "Moving/Feeding", "Standing", "Standing", 
"Standing", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Standing", "Standing", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", "Standing", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", "Standing", "Standing", "Standing", 
"Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Moving/Feeding", "Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Standing", "Standing", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", "Standing", 
"Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Standing", "Moving/Feeding", "Standing", "Standing", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Standing", "Standing", "Moving/Feeding", "Standing", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Moving/Feeding", 
"Standing")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -215L))
```

Any input is appreciated!

Comment: What is the point of turning to `factor` ? `observed` has 3 while `new_predicted` has two, thus your error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about just doing as follows without converting to factors,

```
mean(test_accuracy$observed == test_accuracy$new_predicted)
# 0.5069767
```